# Call to a member function real_escape_string() on array in

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I am struggling with something strange.  I am running a mysqli::real_escape_string on a function to prepare an SQL statement.  I am taking data from one database and developing a query to insert it into a database on a different server.

There error message I get is:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on array in ...

I tried logging a is_array() function right before calling the real_escape_string() and it confirms that it is not an array.  I am getting this whether I pass in a numeric or a string value.   I thought perhaps it was an encoding issue, but I'm not sure how to deal with those.  I tried to convert it before, but that also didn't work:

```
$str = $row[$key];                     // Tried on two strings '1' (is_numeric = True), and 'Kevin'
is_array( $str );                      // Returns False
$str = mb_convert_encoding($row[$key], 'UTF-8');    // Consequently, also tried 'latin1' with the same result.
$db->real_escape_string( $str );
```

That also did not work, still is returning the array error.

Any other suggestions on what to try?

Thanks.

Comment: i trust php if it says its an array, it is

Comment: What is in $db?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that it's your $db is array, not the function's parameter

Comment: Wow, so obvious, I should have thought of that!  You were right, that was the problem. I was so focused on $str I didn't think to look at $db.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Check your variable with function var_dump()

```
var_dump($str);
```